# Modelling 0-1 data that includes 0s GLM

Tags: r, distributions, generalized-linear-model

I have a response variable that lies between 0-1 and could include both 0 and 1 and all values in between and is not proportional data. I thought I could sue a binomial distribution for this but I'm not sure that is right. My current model is below. I'm looking to see if two predictors (which are factors) interact with the response variable.

```
SE_mod <- glm(SE_score ~ atoll*year, 
          family=quasibinomial(), data=REC.RESET_filt, na.action = "na.fail")

summary(SE_mod)
```

I'm aware you can use beta regression for values between 0 and 1 but they can't include exactly values of 0 and 1. Is a quasibinomial distribution OK for this kind of data? Or could the values be transformed so they can be used in a beta regression?

A reproducible dataset is below.

```
structure(list(station = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("AR01", 
"BE01", "BE02", "BEUWM01", "BL01", "BL02", "GCB01", "GCB02", 
"GCB03", "GCB04", "NI01", "NI01b", "NI02", "NI03", "PB01", "PB02", 
"PB03", "PB04", "PB05", "PB06", "PB07", "PB08", "PB09", "PB10", 
"PB11", "PB12", "PB13", "PB14", "PB15", "PB16", "PB17", "PB18", 
"PB19", "PB20", "PB21", "PB22", "PB23", "PB24", "PB25", "PB26", 
"PB27", "PB28", "PB29", "PB30", "PB4G01", "PB4G02", "PBUWM01", 
"PBUWM02", "SA01", "SA02", "SA02b", "SA03", "SA04", "SA05", "SA06", 
"SA07", "SA11", "SA4G01", "SAUWM01", "SB01", "SB02/AR02", "SB03/AR05", 
"SB04/AR06", "VB01", "VB02", "VB03", "VB04"), class = "factor"), 
    monthyear = structure(1:6, levels = c("2014/01", "2014/02", 
    "2014/03", "2014/04", "2014/05", "2014/06", "2014/07", "2014/08", 
    "2014/09", "2014/10", "2014/11", "2014/12", "2015/01", "2015/02", 
    "2015/03", "2015/04", "2015/05", "2015/06", "2015/07", "2015/08", 
    "2015/09", "2015/10", "2015/11", "2015/12", "2016/01", "2016/02", 
    "2016/03", "2016/04", "2016/05", "2016/06", "2016/07", "2016/08", 
    "2016/09", "2016/10", "2016/11", "2016/12", "2017/01", "2017/02", 
    "2017/03", "2017/04", "2017/05", "2017/06", "2017/07", "2017/08", 
    "2017/09", "2017/10", "2017/11", "2017/12", "2018/01", "2018/02", 
    "2018/03", "2018/04", "2018/05", "2018/06", "2018/07", "2018/08", 
    "2018/09", "2018/10", "2018/11", "2018/12"), class = "factor"), 
    SE_score = c(0.19, 0.17, 0.22, 0.21, 0.22, 0.13), atoll = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Benares", "Blenheim", "Peros Banhos", 
    "Saloman", "Victory Bank"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(16071, 
    16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222), class = "Date"), year = c("2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014"), month = c(1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 6), yr_grps = c("Jan-Jun 2014", "Jan-Jun 2014", 
    "Jan-Jun 2014", "Jan-Jun 2014", "Jan-Jun 2014", "Jan-Jun 2014"
    ), Date_num = c(0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    station = structure(2L, levels = c("AR01", "BE01", "BE02", 
    "BEUWM01", "BL01", "BL02", "GCB01", "GCB02", "GCB03", "GCB04", 
    "NI01", "NI01b", "NI02", "NI03", "PB01", "PB02", "PB03", 
    "PB04", "PB05", "PB06", "PB07", "PB08", "PB09", "PB10", "PB11", 
    "PB12", "PB13", "PB14", "PB15", "PB16", "PB17", "PB18", "PB19", 
    "PB20", "PB21", "PB22", "PB23", "PB24", "PB25", "PB26", "PB27", 
    "PB28", "PB29", "PB30", "PB4G01", "PB4G02", "PBUWM01", "PBUWM02", 
    "SA01", "SA02", "SA02b", "SA03", "SA04", "SA05", "SA06", 
    "SA07", "SA11", "SA4G01", "SAUWM01", "SB01", "SB02/AR02", 
    "SB03/AR05", "SB04/AR06", "VB01", "VB02", "VB03", "VB04"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: You may want to try a ZOIB model (Zero-One inflated beta).  As you mention, beta regression does not support observations on the endpoints of the unit interval.  However, if you model those observations as a separate process then they can be accommodated.  However, to date I believe the only implementation of the ZOIB family is in the `brms` library, which means you will necessarily have to analyze your data using a Bayesian framework.

Comment: Do the zeros and ones occur because they are the average of binary events? If that's the case, then a beta-binomial distribution is probably what you want to look at.

Comment: No it's a score dependent on certain values of an environmental variable. If below a certain value 0 above 1 and in between a value defined by a linear function. I think a zero-one inlfated beta as recommended above is the right approach. This blog was very informative about this topic https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2021/11/08/beta-regression-guide/